# DataGridView is empty after loading data from XML

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

I would like to load an XML page into a `DataGridView`. On the page is nested node "Cube". I have a problem with the LINQ expression since it is all the time `null`.

```
 XElement xml = XElement.Load("http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml");
 var xmlData = from item in xml.Descendants("Cube")
               select new {
                 Currency = item.Attribute("currency").Value,
                 Rate = item.Attribute("rate").Value                       
               };
 dataGridView1.DataSource = xmlData.ToList();
```

**Update**

I'm use `XmlNodeList` and I passed in object `doc` tag "Cube". Currently in the loop I have 33 nodes Cube and I would like to display child element currency and rate . But I have an error "System.NullReferenceException: 'An object reference was not set to an object instance.'

```
 private void LoadCurrency()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNodeList nodeList;
        doc.Load("http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml");
        nodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Cube");
        for(int i=0;i<nodeList.Count;i++)
        {
            string str = String.Format("Currency={0} Rate={1}",nodeList[i].ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText, nodeList[i].ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText);
            listBox1.Items.Add(str.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Any help or suggestion is welcome.

Comment: `Cube` is not the root element of the loaded file. The root element is `gesmes:Envelope` so `xml.Descendants("Cube")` returns empty/null which is correct.

Comment: It's a poor API that names elements exactly the same in 3 levels of nesting.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `ItemsSource` instead:

`dataGridView1.ItemsSource = xmlData.ToList();`